# How to apply date formula in Apache p o i?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am setting the formula but when i evaluate it .Some garbage value is displayed. for example Date is "20170801" then it should display "8/1/2017" but it is not instead it is displaying a number "42948" .
When i am using the dragFormula methods to drag a certain formula from a certain cell address upto a certain point then date is evaluating correctly in sheet.
I need help in applying the date formula.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFEvaluationWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaRenderer;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.AreaPtg;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.Ptg;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.RefPtgBase;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 *
 * @author Agent-47
 */
public class Formula {
    Workbook workbook ;
    final static int VERTICAL_UP = -1;
    final static int VERTICAL_DOWN = 1;
    final static int HORIZONTALLY_RIGHT = 2;
    final static int HORIZONTALLY_LEFT = -2;
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException{
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Agent-47\\Desktop\\Book1.xls";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        Formula obj1 = new Formula();
        Workbook book = obj1.createWorkbook(fis, filePath);
        Sheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
        //obj1.dragFormulaVeritacally(sheet, "B1", 6,Formula.VERTICAL_DOWN);
        String formula = "DATE(LEFT(A1,4),LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),2),RIGHT(A1,2))";
        obj1.applyFormula(sheet, formula, "A1");
        book.write(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
    }

    public Workbook createWorkbook(FileInputStream fis,String filePath) throws IOException{
        Workbook workbook = null;
        if(filePath.endsWith(".xls")){
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        }
        else if(filePath.endsWith(".xlsx")){
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        }
        return workbook;
    }
    public  void dragFormulaVeritacally(Sheet sheet,String cellAddress,int uptoRow,int direction){
        if(sheet==null){
            System.out.println("Sheet is null");
            return;
        }
        CellReference cellRefernce = new CellReference(cellAddress);
        int formulaRow = cellRefernce.getRow();
        int formulaColumn = cellRefernce.getCol();
        FormulaEvaluator eval = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        Cell oldCell = sheet.getRow(formulaRow).getCell(formulaColumn);
        if(oldCell!=null){
            String formula ;
            if(oldCell.getCellTypeEnum()== CellType.FORMULA){
                formula = oldCell.getCellFormula();
                try{
                    eval.evaluateInCell(oldCell);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("This cell has issues at row : "+oldCell.getRowIndex()+" column index : "+oldCell.getColumnIndex());
                }
                if(oldCell.isPartOfArrayFormulaGroup()){
                    System.out.println("Formula is a part of array Group");
                    return;
                }

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Cant copy cuz it is not a formula : ");
                return;
            }

            eval.evaluateInCell(oldCell);
            //boolean forCheck = true;
            for(int i=formulaRow;;){
                if(formulaRow+1<uptoRow){
                    if(i>=uptoRow-1)
                        break;
                    else
                        i++;
                }
                else{
                    if(i<=uptoRow-1)
                        break;
                    else
                        i--;
                }
                System.out.println(" i : "+i);
                Row newRow = sheet.getRow(i);
                if(newRow==null)
                    newRow = sheet.createRow(i);
                Cell newCell = newRow.getCell(formulaColumn);
                if(newCell==null)
                    newCell = newRow.createCell(formulaColumn);
                try{
                    if(direction==Formula.VERTICAL_DOWN)
                        formula=copyFormula(sheet,formula,newCell,1,0);
                    else if(direction==Formula.VERTICAL_UP)
                        formula=copyFormula(sheet,formula,newCell,-1,0);
                    eval.evaluateInCell(newCell);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("This cell has issues at row : "+newCell.getRowIndex()+" column index : "+newCell.getColumnIndex());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public  void dragFormulaHorizontally(Sheet sheet,String cellAddress,String uptoColumn,int direction){
    if(sheet==null){
        System.out.println("Sheet is null");
        return;
    }
    CellReference cellRefernce = new CellReference(cellAddress);
    CellReference uptoColumnReference = new CellReference(uptoColumn);
    int uptoColumnIndex = uptoColumnReference.getCol();
    int formulaRow = cellRefernce.getRow();
    int formulaColumn = cellRefernce.getCol();
    FormulaEvaluator eval = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    Cell oldCell = sheet.getRow(formulaRow).getCell(formulaColumn);
    if(oldCell!=null){
        String formula;
        if(oldCell.getCellTypeEnum()== CellType.FORMULA){
            formula = oldCell.getCellFormula();
            try{
                eval.evaluateInCell(oldCell);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("This cell has issues at row : "+oldCell.getRowIndex()+" column index : "+oldCell.getColumnIndex());
            }
            if(oldCell.isPartOfArrayFormulaGroup()){
                System.out.println("Formula is a part of array Group");
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Cant copy cuz it is not a formula : ");
            return;
        }
        //boolean forCheck = true;
        for(int i=formulaColumn;;){
            if(formulaRow+1<uptoColumnIndex){
                if(i>=uptoColumnIndex)
                    break;
                else
                    i++;
            }
            else{
                if(i<=uptoColumnIndex)
                    break;
                else
                    i--;
            }
            Row newRow = sheet.getRow(formulaRow);
            if(newRow==null)
                newRow = sheet.createRow(formulaRow);
            Cell newCell = newRow.getCell(i);
            if(newCell==null)
                newCell = newRow.createCell(i);
            try{
                if(direction==Formula.HORIZONTALLY_RIGHT)
                    formula=copyFormula(sheet,formula,newCell,0,1);
                else if(direction==Formula.HORIZONTALLY_LEFT)
                    formula=copyFormula(sheet,formula,newCell,0,-1);
                eval.evaluateInCell(newCell);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("This cell has issues at row : "+newCell.getRowIndex()+" at column : "+newCell.getColumnIndex());
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

}





    public String copyFormula(Sheet sheet,String formula,Cell newCell,int incRow,int incColumn){
        HSSFEvaluationWorkbook workbookEval = HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((HSSFWorkbook)sheet.getWorkbook());
        Ptg[] ptgs = FormulaParser.parse(formula, workbookEval, FormulaType.CELL, sheet.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(sheet));
        for(int i=0;i<ptgs.length;i++){
            if(ptgs[i] instanceof RefPtgBase){
                RefPtgBase ref = (RefPtgBase)ptgs[i];
                System.out.println("Ref Ptg");
                if(ref.isRowRelative())
                    ref.setRow(ref.getRow()+incRow);
                if(ref.isColRelative())
                    ref.setColumn(ref.getColumn()+incColumn);
            }
            else if(ptgs[i] instanceof AreaPtg){
                AreaPtg area = (AreaPtg)ptgs[i];
                System.out.println("Area Ptg");
                if(area.isFirstColRelative())
                    area.setFirstColumn(area.getFirstColumn()+incColumn);
                if(area.isFirstRowRelative())
                    area.setFirstRow(area.getFirstRow()+incRow);
                if(area.isLastColRelative())
                    area.setLastColumn(area.getLastColumn()+incColumn);
                if(area.isLastRowRelative())
                    area.setLastRow(area.getLastRow()+incRow);
            }
            formula = FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString(workbookEval, ptgs);
            newCell.setCellFormula(formula);
        }
        return formula;
    }

    // apply formula at single cell
    public void applyFormula(Sheet sheet,String formula,String atColumnAddress){
        //List<Cell> cellValues = new LinkedList<>();
        FormulaEvaluator eval = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        CellReference atColumnReference = new CellReference(atColumnAddress);
        int atColumnIndex = atColumnReference.getCol();
        int atRowIndex = atColumnReference.getRow();
        Cell oldCell = sheet.getRow(atRowIndex).getCell(atColumnIndex);
        Cell cell = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1).createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
        cell.setCellFormula(formula);

        //copyFormula(sheet, formula, cell, 0, 0); ///---------calling the copy formula method
        System.out.println("Date is : "+eval.evaluateInCell(cell));
    }

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756748/apache-poi-date-format

Comment: .... Just needed to add the format but still one

Comment: CellStyle cs = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        DataFormat df = sheet.getWorkbook().createDataFormat();
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("m/d/yyyy"));
        cell.setCellStyle(cs);

Comment: Problem is solved but why style is not needed when draging the same formula.

Comment: `Excel` stores dates as numbers. The number of days since 01/01/1900 where 01/01/1900 == 1. The formula you are dragging was put in `Excel`s GUI. So `Excel` has set data format automatically since it is a `DATE` formula. The `apache poi`really only sets the formula string, not the format automatically. That you need to do additional, to format numbers like 42948 (01/01/1900 + 42947 days) as date.

Comment: Btw.: Sometimes I don't understand how someone can write such complex code using `apache poi` and seems not to have the very basic understanding of the `Microsoft Office`, he is creating files for.

Comment: Thanks again @Axel Richter....Do i really need to study the MSOffice thoroughly to create such a program ? I am still learning as soon as i learn something i start writting code to implement it. True, i am new to MS office but great people like you are there to help new learners like me .

Comment: "Do i really need to study the MS Office thoroughly to create such a program?": Absolutely yes in my opinion. Not only this but also the standards of the [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file system and, if needed, also the legacy binary file formats up to `Office 2003`, since `apache poi` upto today is the opposite of a ready to use library but highly in development until now. Thus you often will be stuck and helpless without knowledge of the backgrounds.

Comment: Alright! then i will give it a try..